# How to get the selected value variables from select list and assign it as global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javaScript code that need to get the values from selected options.

what i'm looking for is.

1. Get the value of selected option of serverName and assign it as
   global variable.
2. Get the value of selected option of targetApp and assign it as global variable.

so for example, if select App2 and ServerC the variables values should be something like.

```
var AppName = App2
var hostName = ServerC
```

not sure how to add that to this code.

Note:
     I don't have good experience in Javascript, but I have to get this done, so any help will be appreciated.

JS

```
var serverName = {
    App1: ["Server1", "Server2", "Server3"],
    App2: ["ServerA", "ServerB", "ServerC"],
    App3: ["ServerX", "ServerY", "ServerZ"]
}

    function changecat(value) {
        if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
        else {
            var catOptions = "";
            for (categoryId in serverName[value]) {
                catOptions += "<option>" + serverName[value][categoryId] + "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("category").innerHTML = catOptions;
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java1.js"></script>

    <select name="targetApp" id="targetApp" onChange="changecat(this.value);">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="App1">App</option>
        <option value="App">App</option>
        <option value="App">App</option>
    </select>
    <select name="category" id="category">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Just set them to `window.AppName` or `window.hostName`. The `window` isn't necessary, but it makes it clearer what you're doing

Comment: what you are trying to do in change event??

Comment: This is not Jquery.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind making it global?